# Refer to entry of input matrix in SparseArray

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

The code

```
generate[matrix_] := Module[{n}, n := Dimensions[matrix][[1]];
                     Normal@Simplify@SparseArray[{
                     {i_, j_} /; i == 1 -> 2
                     }, {n, n}]]

a := {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
generate[a]
```

produces

```
{{2, 2}, {0, 0}}
```

(of course there is no need to define the matrix `a` in the first place in this case). Now consider the modification

```
generate[matrix_] := Module[{n}, n := Dimensions[matrix][[1]];
                     Normal@Simplify@SparseArray[{
                     {i_, j_} /; i == 1 -> matrix[[i,j]]
                     }, {n, n}]]

a := {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
generate[a]
```

where I only changed `2` into `matrix[[i,j]]`. Just like the first example generates a 2x2 matrix with zeros everywhere and fills in the first row with 2's, I would expect the second snippet of code to generate a matrix whose first row is the same as that of the input matrix `a`. Instead, I get the error message

```
Part: The expression i$ cannot be used as a part specification.
```

How would I go about solving this? Of course in this example I could just set each entry manually, but this example is just a proxy of the more complicated case I'm working with. I'm new to Mathematica. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Use `:>` ([`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)) instead of `->` ([`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html)) to prevent evaluation of the `matrix[[i,j]]` part before `i` and `j` are substituted.

Comment: @LukasLang thanks!!